# Should I use asyncTask or a Service to contact my server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have the android app, and i have a server side.

I want to perform the following background job:
Contact the server every 60 seconds, "ask" him if some condition is met, and when the condition met, i want to show an alert dialog to the user, with OK and Close buttons. if the user clicks OK, an Activity should be brought to front.

i read about asynkTask and Service, but could not decide which one to use

should i use this task in asynkTask or Service?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an AsyncTask is probably easier, as a) the query to the server in doInBackground will not block the UI and b) onPostExecute executes in the UI thread/context which makes it easy to report OK or Close.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea if you want the task to run all the time (even when the app is not open) - I'd use a service for a long running, headless task like this. To use an AsyncTask, you are going to need your app to be open so it is able to handle the result.